# "synaptic: error while loading shared libraries: libept.so.1.aptpkg4.12"

Tags: synaptic

When I start synaptic, it throws the following:

```
$ sudo synaptic
[sudo] password for xxxxx: 
synaptic: error while loading shared libraries: libept.so.1.aptpkg4.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What is the reason and what is its solution?

Comment: Hey Tabrez try gksudo synaptic. While I look into this.

Comment: looks like you do not have libept installed. try installing it then report back

Comment: @mojo706, Thanks for replying and sorry that I disappeared as soon as I asked the question. Synaptic was just fine yesterday. And yes, libept is installed already.

Comment: Where is it exactly? What's the output of `locate libept.so.1.aptpkg4.12`?

Comment: @Braiam You might want to post something like that as an answer. **Tabrez Ahmed:** Did you install any software since Synaptic last worked? (I'm especially thinking of software installed *not* through the package manager, but please tell us about *any* software.) Did you edit your `ldconfig` configuration, for example by adding anything inside `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reinstall `libept1.4.2` since for some reason or other is not present in the `/usr/lib` directory. For doing so:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libept1.4.12
```

You may check if it exist or not doing:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libept.so.1.aptpkg4.12
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 596740 jun 21  2012 /usr/lib/libept.so.1.aptpkg4.12
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got an equivalent error message for using synaptic with libept1.4.16. 
The problem is that the necessary library libept.so.1.aptpkg4.16 doesn't exist, but libept.so.1.aptpkg5.0 can be found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ instead of that.
Indeed libept1.4.16_1.0.14+b2_amd64.deb seems to be faulty. It claims to be libept1.4.16, but in reality it installs libept1.5.0 instead of this.
To solve the problem I just copied libept.so.1.aptpkg4.16 from the older version libept1.4.16_1.0.14+b1_amd64.deb to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ and used ldconfig -v afterwards. Now synaptic starts again.